# Map view span changes when updating the location

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have a function in my view controller with a mapkit that is called when the location changes. I would like set to the map view so that is is centered around the current location and moves with it as it updates.

It works in a sense i.e it tracks along, however it is always **zoomed** in really far. If **I zoom out** it **snaps** back to where it was when it calls the update again after getting a new location.

```
in from params CLLocation *loc
bool first = TRUE;
if(first){
        first=FALSE; // bit of a bodge...if i set this to false it will track the update possition but not at the desired "zoom" its look far to close.
        CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:54.976619 longitude:-1.613118];//newcastle city center.
        CLLocationDegrees spanLat = 1000;
        CLLocationDegrees spanLng = 1000;  
        userLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc.coordinate, spanLat, spanLng);
        [mapview setRegion:userLocation animated:TRUE];
    }else {
        CLLocationDegrees spanLat = [mapview region].span.latitudeDelta;//  keep the originals? DOESN'T WORK!!
        CLLocationDegrees spanLng = [mapview region].span.longitudeDelta;//  
        userLocation = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(loc.coordinate, spanLat, spanLng);
        [mapview setRegion:userLocation animated:TRUE];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep setting the center coordinate and don't set the region.

By the way, you do know that you don't need any of that code, right? You can just tell the mapview to track the device's current location. See my book for an example:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch34.html#_map_kit_and_current_location

Comment: Cool thanks. I did have the first part the off in the view did load. but that didnt seem to work. set center in the second part of the if works. But i do need to get rid of that if thats why i said it was a bit of a bodge.